# First python script - Import error on constant

Tags: python, debian

This is the start of the python script I've made.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import constant
import sys,datetime,time,logging
import boto
```

However when I try to run it, I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named constant
```

My understanding is that constant should be a part of the Python standard libs. My python version is 3 and I'm running Debian 7.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a link for the documentation of the module "Constant?" I am not able to find it.

Comment: what do you think the `constant` module is/does?

Comment: From the code it is quite obvious that this is a custom module containing configuration parameters.

Comment: It is not relevant how you are using the `constant` module... it is not part of the standard library, so no matter how you want to use it you will need to install it yourself.

Comment: Jan is right.  You are missing a custom module named constant.  constant.QNAME is just the name of the queue.  Name it Bob if you want to....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python standard library does not have any module named `constant`.

The closest thing I could find is [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/) but this is far from the standard library.

Perhaps you were confused by the term "module level constant" which indicates a variable (not actually contstant) declared at module scope?  You can import a specific constant variable with `from module import GLOBAL_CONST` where `module` is an actual module and `GLOBAL_CONST` is an actual constant defined in that module

Comment: I put my full code in the comment which should show what was trying to be achived

Comment: @Jimmy and where is it that you saw this `constant` module in use?

Answer (score 3):

There is no module named constant in the [The Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/). So this wont work.

What do you want to achieve with it ?

Comment: Let me take a guess - if you have copied this from somewhere else, there is an accompanying file/ custom made module called constant.py which you have failed to copy.